# Split string using delimiter “\” in python windows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, operating-system

I am facing problem in getting column with just ID names. The Id name should not consist of any path attached to it. The code seems to work fine in Ubuntu but not in Windows. Here is the code snippet:

```
pd.DataFrame({"patientId": [each_train_dicom.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]]
```

Comment: what is `each_train_dicom`? Also you say that the code does not work on windows, what are your experiencing (i.e., an error, unexpected results, etc.)

Comment: Can you provide an working (string) example?

Comment: for i, each_train_dicom in enumerate(list_of_train_dicoms):   this. Thank you for replying, The problem has been solved though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `os.path.sep` as the separator character instead of hardcoding "\"

```
import os

s = r"C:\Windows\Folder\file.txt"
print(s.split(os.path.sep))
```